# Collapsible with checkall in header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I try to make a checkall in header of collapsible like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8TvL3/)

[image]

But that's not working. It's not running my script. Here is my code

```
$('h3').on( "click", 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    alert('run'); // not working
    $("input[name='"+this.name+"']")
        .attr({
            checked: $(this).is(':checked')
        });
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
    $("input[name='"+this.name+"']").checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

How to make that working well? thanks

Comment: Your code changes DOM and hides the `input[type=checkbox]` below the label so checkbox is not clicked .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the click to the label, like this:

```
$('label').on( "click", function(e) {
  var cb = $("input[type=checkbox]");
  if(cb.prop('checked')){
      cb.prop('checked', false);
  }else{
      cb.prop('checked', true);
  }
  cb.checkboxradio("refresh");
  return false; // Don't collapse
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8TvL3/12/

Comment: I'm not sure but i think there is a touch event for mobile

Comment: After a quick search: `$('label').on('touchstart click', function(){ /* do something... */ });` This creates an event for both touch and click